# BlackBerry OS6 WebWorks limiting ajax request to 10, is there a connection leakage?

Tags: ajax, blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a webworks application using phonegap and jquerymobile. I use soapclient.js to create soap requests to my backend server. We were facing a timeout issue and during detailed investigation we noticed that consistently the 11th ajax request gets a no response. To put things on right place we repeated the test with same calls repeat so that we know that the particular request works.

we use the low end self created xmlhttprequest object and till the send() call there are no errors. The onreadystate change listener doesn't get called for the 11th call.

Occasionally when we waited long enough this 11th call did get honoured in approx 5 mins or so, making me believe that there is a connection leakage in BlackBerry browserfield.

I suspect that there is a limit of 10 connection (non parallel) which can be made. After sometime when BB garbage clean up triggers in, it clears out few old connection the new connection waiting in queue gets executed.

**More info**

1. I have verified from server logs that during this waiting period,
   server didn't received the request
2. I have verified that this
   happens irrespective of whether I use Wi-Fi or GPRS
3. The application starts working again, if I close and reopens it but only till the
   first 10 requests

I have tried to abort the request if it passes my timeout period by calling abort() and setting it to null. But even then I cannot make the 11th request if I don't wait for some time.

I would have believed any other reasons like javascript waiting for UI thread etc, if this behavior would have been random. But it is 99% reproducible on the 11th request and I have rechecked the code multiple times to see if there is any variable or count being informed from the app. The alert works fine till .send but the callback is not called.

I am now trying to create a very plain app which makes ajax calls to see if this behavior is specific to my app or is it a platform constraint, but if anybody has any such previous experience please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a day of struggle, we found that it was happening due to assigning javascript functions to hardware keys. Since we were using different menu items under different jQuery page, the menu button is bound to different javascript functions on various activities, which was resulting in memory leakage in BB WebWorks application. We got it resolved when we bound the menu hardware button with a global variable and kept on replacing its assignment instead of recalling bind again and again.